# Class 'Users' Not found Laravel 4.2 Users::all();

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am just trying to have my users table printed out onto a page. I am getting a Class `Users` Not found in Laravel 4.2 - I have dump-autoloaded and clear compiled.

My users.php is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}
```

My controller file reads (I've redacted code -- the issue is 100% this portion of code, as it works if I just pass messages to the view:

```
<?php

class SearchController extends BaseController {

public function search()
{
    $search = Input::get("Search_Input");
    $search_terms = explode(",", $search);
    $search_query_type = Input::get("search_type");
    $search_type = 'null';

    if ($search_type === "Rep_Name") {
       $users = Users::all();
       return Redirect::to('/search')->with('users', $users);
     }
}
```

My search view has this code:

```
    @foreach($users as $name)
        {{ $name->Name }}
    @endforeach
```

My database has a users table and a Name row.

The laravel.log error I get is:

> [2016-04-28 19:32:30] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Users' not found' in /home3/circates/public_html/jon/repform/app/controllers/SearchController.php:50
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
>       #1 {main} [] []

Comment: Your class is defined as User, not Users.

Comment: Why do people just love to see a comment that is quite correct and turn it into the answer selfishly taking all the credit. Beats me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **SearchController.php** file, you need change `Users:all()` into `User::all()`, because your class is defined as `User`, as is mentioned in the comment by Fabio Thomaz.

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {

public function search()
{
    $search = Input::get("Search_Input");
    $search_terms = explode(",", $search);
    $search_query_type = Input::get("search_type");
    $search_type = 'null';

    if ($search_type === "Rep_Name") {
       $users = User::all();
       return Redirect::to('/search')->with('users', $users);
     }
}
```

Comment: And make sure that you have the `use path\to\user\model` on the top of the code. If he doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is "User" and the file name is "users.php"

Change the file name to "User.php"

And u can call it from the SearchController as:

```
User::all();
```